# Dynamically change keyboard type - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change the keyboard dynamically. the keyboard starts in `TextInputType.text`, when the user types 3 letters it is switched to `TextInputType.number` and the user types 4 numbers. ex: `ABC1234`.

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: "code",
  hintText: 'ABC1234'),
  controller: _myController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
),
```

Answer (score 6):

##### Here is your working code

> The keyboard is also changed automatically

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
late FocusNode myFocusNode = FocusNode();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Center(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: TextFormField(
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
          keyboardType: (_controller.text.length >= 3) ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.name,
          onChanged: (text) {
            if (_controller.text != text.toUpperCase()) {
              _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(text: text.toUpperCase());
            }
            if (_controller.text.length == 3){
              setState(() {
                myFocusNode.unfocus();
                Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50)).then((value) {
                  myFocusNode.requestFocus();
                });
              });
            }
          },
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]'))
          ],
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'ABC1234')),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @Rodriguessilva It's already changing as like you can see in Gif

Comment: @Rodriguessilva You need to handle the same things on erase any character from TextField

Comment: The onChanged is not fired when the user moves only the cursor, say by tapping elsewhere on the text field, so this code is 'partially complete'. Perhaps you can help with managing this too...

Comment: `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => textFieldFocusNode.requestFocus(),);` is more appropriate than `Future.delayed()`

Answer (score 2):

To change your `TextInputType` dynamically, what you can do is:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
//Creating a variable to store the type and initializing it with the default text type.
var keyboardType = TextInputType.text;

TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: "code",
  hintText: 'ABC1234'),
  controller: _myController,
  //Passing the variable created in here
  keyboardType: keyboardType,
  onChanged: (value) {
    //Checking if the value's length is less than 4, if it is, it should be type `text`.
    if(value.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
      setState(() => keyboardType = TextInputType.text);
    } else {
      //Else, it should be type `number`
      setState(() => keyboardType = TextInputType.number);
    }
  }  
),
```

The will change the keyboard type dynamically but it may not change the keyboard, and you may have to close and open the keyboard again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyboardType like this. It will be for both numbers and letters.

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare a variable like your controller for keyboardtype, where keyboardtype is variable and TextInputTupe is it's datatype.

```
TextInputType keyboardtype = TextInputType.text;
```

now, check yout textformfield's String, If your string.length is greater than 3 then keyboard type is `TextInputType.number`

check the length into onchanged in textformfield

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
TextInputType keyboardType = TextInputType.text;
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: "code",
  hintText: 'ABC1234'),
  controller: _myController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  onChanged: (value){
    var inputText = _myController.text;
    if(inputText.length>3){
      keyBoardType = TextInputType.number;
    }
  }
),
```

> It would be better if you use some regex to check your inputformat into the `inputFormatters` in your textformfield. if you don't know about inputformatters just google it.

Comment: The keyboard not changed with this code